# PHP Error on a Webserver

Tags: php

This is an auto promotion system (written in php) for a website, however it seems to give an error that I'm not familiar with. I replaced the website name with 'example' for privacy reasons.

```
<?php
$group_id         = $_GET['groupId'];
$new_role_set_id  = $_GET['newRoleSetId'];
$target_user_id   = $_GET['targetUserId'];


$login_user       = 'username=user&password=pass';
$file_path_rs     = 'rs.txt';
$file_path_token  = 'token.txt';
$current_rs       = file_get_contents($file_path_rs);
$current_token    = file_get_contents($file_path_token);


function getRS()
{
    global $login_user, $file_path_rs;

    $get_cookies = curl_init('https://www.example.com/newlogin');
    curl_setopt_array($get_cookies,
        array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            // CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Content-Length: " .                 strlen($login_user)),
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $login_user
)
);

$rs = (preg_match('/(\.SECURITY=.*?);/', curl_exec($get_cookies), $matches) ? $matches[1] : '');
file_put_contents($file_path_rs, $rs, true);
curl_close($get_cookies);

return $rs;
}


function changeRank($rs, $token) 
{
global $group_id, $new_role_set_id, $target_user_id, $file_path_token;

$promote_user = curl_init("http://www.example.com/groups/api/change-member-        rank?    groupId=$group_id&newRoleSetId=$new_role_set_id&targetUserId=$target_user_id");
curl_setopt_array($promote_user,
    array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Cookie: $rs", "X-CSRF-TOKEN: $token")
    )
);

$resp = curl_exec($promote_user);
$resp_header_size = curl_getinfo($promote_user, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$resp_header = substr($resp, 0, $resp_header_size);
$resp_body = substr($resp, $resp_header_size);

if (preg_match('/GuestData/', $resp_header)) {

    $resp_body = changeRank( getRS(), $token );
} else if (preg_match('/Token Validation Failed/', $resp_header)) {

    $new_token = (preg_match('/X-CSRF-TOKEN: (\S+)/', $resp_header,     $matches) ? $matches[1] : '');
    file_put_contents($file_path_token, $new_token, true);
    $resp_body = changeRank( $rs, $new_token );
}

curl_close($promote_user);

return $resp_body;
}


echo changeRank($current_rs, $current_token);
```

When accessing the page I get the page error:

Bad Request - Invalid Content Length

```
HTTP Error 400. There is an invalid content length or chunk length in the request.
```

I'm not sure why this is happening, and I've tried just about everything, even switching hosts, but the issue still arises. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: In changeRank, you set CURLOPT_POST to true, but don't add any post data